# how can one make a mongoDB field of type map of map

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am kinda new to mongoose and have an existing schema that looks like this

```
const folder = new Schema({
  files: {
    type: Map,
    of: String
  },
})
```

and i want files field to be something like this:

```
          files: {
            '054wrtrd': { 'fileName': "hello.js", 'editLink': "none", 'downloadLink': "none" },
            'gdtgeyev5': { 'fileName': "bye.js", 'editLink': "none", 'downloadLink': "none" },
          },
```

however, i am getting this error

```
 {
        "stringValue": "\"{ fileName: 'none', editLink: 'none', downloadLink: 'none' }\"",
        "valueType": "Object",
        "kind": "string",
        "value": {
            "fileName": "none",
            "editLink": "none",
            "downloadLink": "none"
        },
        "path": "files.$*",
        "reason": null,
        "name": "CastError",
        "message": "Cast to string failed for value \"{ fileName: 'none', editLink: 'none', downloadLink: 'none' }\" (type Object) at path \"files.$*\""
    }
```

Is there a way to set the field type to be like Map:Map or something along those lines?
plus how would i retrieve for instance fileName

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I found the answer, i needed to declare the files field like this way

```
    const folder = new Schema({
      files: {
        type: Map,
        of: {
          fileName: { type: String },
          editLink: { type: String },
          downloadLink: { type: String },
        },
      },
    });
```

Comment: That schema looks right for the files field you describe.  What code results in that error?